# MS Access: Type Conversion Error (Double to Long Integer)

Tags: r, database, csv, ms-access

I'm working on a data set in R that I have converted some fields into double using `as.double()` then export it in to CSV format.

My work also requires importing such CSV into MS Access.
When I imported the CSV file, Access automatically treated those double fields as long integer. I thought it should be fine as none of the values are above 100M.

However, Access gave me the error message of Type Conversion Error on those double fields. 
I tried choosing them to be double instead of long integer during importing wizard which was work but that isn't very efficient as I have to import many more tables. Selecting the fields for every time I do it manually is time consuming and error-proned.

Are there any other way, either before I export CSV from R or before importing into MS Access, that will make Access no longer sees double as long integer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using intermediate table with field type like you want ?

Comment: what are those intermediate tables?

Comment: are you importing into tables that already exist or creating new tables? And are all of the tables the same format?